# Gentoo: how to install binutils from binary package (because I accidentally deleted it)

Tags: linux, gentoo

I accidentally deleted my binutils and tried to install it as a binary package.

However, `emerge` is always complaining that there is no package by that name.

I downloaded the packages from [here](http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/default-linux/) and simply copied it into `/usr/portage/packages` (and later also in distfiles).

After that I did `chown portage:portage` and tried to install the package:

```
sudo emerge --ask --usepkgonly binutils-2.24-r3.tbz2
```

it tells me to adjust `PKGDIR`, but it is already set to `/usr/portage/packages`.

After that I tried this:

```
sudo emerge --ask --usepkgonly =binutils-2.24-r3
```

which tells me:

```
emerge: there are no binary packages to satisfy "=binutils-2.24-r3".
```

I don't know where my mistake is; it's written correctly and has the right permissions and is in the right location.... (`make.conf` locations are all default).

The last post on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34277011/1305969) didn't help either.

I just found what appears to be a solution:
[Fatal mistake: Uninstalled sys-devel/binutils - emerge don't work anymore](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249391/fatal-mistake-uninstalled-sys-devel-binutils-emerge-dont-work-anymore/249411#249411)
(didn't see it before); however, it doesn't try to solve the problem using binary packages, so it doesn't answer this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, portage fails some internal magic because of some missing utilities from binutils.
You can just unpack binary package in your root partition with `tar -xjf /usr/portage/packages/binutils*bz2 -C /`. Then you can try to reemerge binutils.

Also, are you sure that binpackage you've dowloaded is really tbz2, but not, say, html?

Comment: I did a new install, but as far as I can remember it was tbz2, however I didn't try to unpack it directly... So I guess you are right but I can't confirm this. Should I mark the answer as solved?

Comment: It would be nice :)
You can re-ask the question later if any :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the information about the package from the Packages file, everything from BUILD_TIME to REPO.

Then you can do something like: emerge --usepkg =media-gfx/graphite2-1.3.13 and it will work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Would you like to elaborate on what your suggestion is and how to do it? This will better help the OP and other visitors

Answer (score 0):

It's because /usr/portage/packages needs the category as well.  The binary package should be placed in a subdirectory called sys-devel in packages.